# Marionette show event does not be triggerd

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I want execute show code after any showing any regions. I tried:

```
app.Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
        template: "#layout-template",
        regions: {
            mini1: {
                selector: "#mini1",
                onShow: function () {
                    console.log("triggered!");
                }
            }});
app.layout.mini1.show(new view());
```

But the onShow function does not run. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 way of defining region in list of region:

1. String with selector
2. Object with `selector` and `regionType` properties
3. Region class

So when you pass object you can not specify `onShow` handler. But you can do what you want if you pass extended `Marionette.Region`:

```
var Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: "#layout-template",
    regions: {
        mini1: Marionette.Region.extend({
            el: "#mini1",
            onShow: function () {
                console.log("triggered!");
            }
        })
    }
});
```

You can check this solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/2CvzR/

And documentation is here: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#custom-region-types